# Why is $\langle f+g, f+g \rangle = \langle f, f \rangle + \langle g, f \rangle + \langle f, g \rangle + \langle g,g\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Why is $\langle f+g, f+g \rangle = \langle f, f \rangle + \langle g, f \rangle + \langle  f, g \rangle + \langle g,g\rangle$?

I know that from linearity:

$$\langle f+g, f+g \rangle = \langle f, f+g \rangle + \langle g, f+g \rangle$$

How to proceed?

Side note: It's very tedious writing langle/rangle again and again.

Comment: You've used linearity once, why cant you use it again on $\langle f, f + g \rangle + \langle g, f + g \rangle$?

Comment: What is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$?

Comment: @Cla, shouldn't it be obvious it's an inner product?

Comment: Obvious is that it is a **bilinear** operation. That's enough.

Comment: Then you can use linearity twice..

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only the [axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) of inner products (and that $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a}+\overline{b}$ ($*$)):
\begin{align}
\langle f+g,f+g\rangle &= \langle f,f+g\rangle+\langle g,f+g\rangle &\text{(Linearity in $1$st entry)}\\
&=\overline{\langle f+g,f\rangle} + \overline{\langle f+g,g\rangle}&\text{(Conjugate symmetry)}\\
&=\overline{\langle f,f\rangle+\langle g,f\rangle} + \overline{\langle f,g\rangle+\langle g,g\rangle}&\text{(Linearity in $1$st entry)}\\
&=\overline{\langle f,f\rangle} + \overline{\langle g,f\rangle} + \overline{\langle f,g\rangle}+\overline{\langle g,g\rangle}&\text{($*$)}\\
&= \langle f,f\rangle + \langle f,g\rangle + \langle g,f\rangle + \langle g,g\rangle.&\text{(Conjugate symmetry)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

For symmetric inner product, you do not only have linearity but **bilinearity**. You can use linearity in the second argument to see

$$\langle f, f+g \rangle = \langle f, f \rangle + \langle f, g \rangle$$
$$\langle g, f+g \rangle = \langle g, f \rangle + \langle g, g \rangle$$

Comment: You do not have bilinearity on inner products, only if the vector space is real. For example:

$$\langle f,\alpha g\rangle = \overline{\langle \alpha g,f \rangle} = \overline{\alpha}\overline{\langle g,f\rangle} = \overline{\alpha}\langle f,g\rangle$$

Comment: Yes. So I add the word symmetric. In general it is only Hermitian.